# How to handle SSH links with Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, chromium

I currently use Chromium on a Windows XP desktop. When I click on a link prefixed with ssh:// I'd like it to run Putty, but nothing happens. How can I configure Chromium to execute Putty for such links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome/Chromium does not handle unknown protocol://s by itself, instead it handles it to OS/DE running on parent system, so you just need to register ssh:// protocol for PuTTY.

As the original developer of PuTTY [does not want](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/ssh-url-scheme.html) to implement this feature, there is [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/), a modified version [that should support this feature](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?page=SSH%20Handler&zone=en).

Comment: Thank you! However, the modified version link isnt working anymore. I guess it's http://www.edv-bartl.at/index.php?id=22&L=1

Comment: @Philippe, fixed.

Comment: once again link rot has struck edv-bartl

Comment: @hildred apparently it's gone for good now. http://web.archive.org still hosts the patch, but you'd probably not want to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[PuttyTray](https://puttytray.goeswhere.com/) supports URL handling.

> PuTTY Tray is an improved version of PuTTY. It features some cosmetic changes, and a number of addons to make it more useful and much more fun to use.

Comment: I don't see how to configure this.